Transaction failed: insufficient funds for gas * price + value Blockchain/laravel
`I worked with Ganache, Truffle, PHP 8, and Laravel. I’m running out of time and encountering this error message. Could you please assist me?
"error": "Transaction failed: insufficient funds for gas * price + value"
PS: I’ve tried debugging by increasing the gas price and gas limit in Ganache, using the default settings, and manually increasing these values in the code. I’m attempting to send a small amount from a wallet to a contract created in my Ganache environment.
i tried to debug
i tried to change the values
i tried to minimise the amount
and had changed the gaz price and gas limit in ganache and the amount in the wallet`

It sounds like you don't have enough funds for whatever you're doing. Compare the amounts. This isn't a programming issue, it's an account balance issue.

try increasing your gas limit and wallet funds (not gas price), by a lot, if you are deploying, gas limit need to be higher.

i increased the wallet fund already it s 200000.00 ETH

Are you using render() method if you rendering HTML on the server side?
